# s#arp architecture query - services and repositories

Tags: c#, s#arp-architecture

My controllers use services rather than repositories directly. The services are placed in the ApplicationServices project:

```
public XYZService
        (
            IBlaRepository BlaRepository,
            IBla1Repository Bla1Repository
        )
        {
            Check.Require(BlaRepository != null, "BlaRepository may not be null");
            this.BlaRepository = BlaRepository;
        ....
```

This works fine.

The repositories are implemented as follows:

```
public interface IBlaRepository : IRepository<Bla> (placed in Core/DataInterfaces)

public class BlaRepository : Repository<Bla>, IBlaRepository (placed in Data)
```

Sometimes I can just use the ‘plain’ sharp architecture repository. Is there a way to pass them into the above service? Do I have to register them somewhere?

To clarify this – the contructor of the service looks like this:

```
public XYZService
        (
            Repository<UUU> UUURepository
```

...

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

chris

Comment: Hm, I think this is done automatically by S#arp via ComponentRegistrar.AddComponentsTo, that does container.AddComponentLifeStyle("repositoryWithTypedId", typeof(IRepositoryWithTypedId<,>), typeof(RepositoryWithTypedId<,>), LifestyleType.PerWebRequest); Was it removed in latest S#arp versions?

Comment: Thanks. If I implemnet the interfaces as described everything works 'automatically' - I am strugling a bit with 'plain s#arp reps'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris,
    all you would need to do is refer to your repository as such:

```
    private readonly IRepository<Bla> _blaRepository; 

    public BlaService(IRepository<Bla> blaRepository) 
    { 
         _blaRepository = blaRepository; 
    }
```

This will allow Windsor to inject the repository into your controller with nothing else needed by you.

Alec